# How does the Chop Chop attack effect TKIP?

Tags: encryption, stream-cipher

I know that chop chop attack is because of WEP's insecure checksum mechanism that is CRC32. As TKIP uses MIC along with CRC32 which just makes an attacker to wait for 60 sec upon two mismatch MIC codes. But how does an attacker guess the data by using ARP and Deauth Packets?